# Scoll bar cant locate at the right side of the listbox using grid (Python/Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i need little help..below is my codes:

```
root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
f_right = Frame(root,width = 400,height=h)
f_right.pack(side=RIGHT)
my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(f_right,width=30,orient=VERTICAL)
mylist = Listbox(f_right,width=25,height = h, yscrollcommand = my_scrollbar.set,font=('ariel',12),justify='center')
mylist.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2) # row0,row1,row2,column0,column1 has some button and label design
my_scrollbar.config(command = mylist.yview)
my_scrollbar.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=NS)

for i in range(1000):
     mylist.insert(END,"a"+str(i))

root.mainloop()
```

i try this code with integer items and scroll bar works, but when i try add the item with string, my scroll bar could not work.. please help

Comment: Do you know that `height` option for `Listbox` is number of lines, not pixels?  So `height=h` where `h = root.winfo_screenheight()` will make the listbox very tall.

Comment: oh gosh, thanks for your deep help.. finally know what is the issue.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the listbox occupies column 0 and 1 due to `columnspan=2`, and the scrollbar is put in column 1 which is covered by the listbox.

Move the scrollbar to column 2 and also set the `sticky` option to `NS`:

```py
my_scrollbar.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=NS)
```

Comment: i see the scrollbar now, but i cant reach my result which beyond the list box frame, my scrollbar not working.

Comment: @BrianTung The scrollbar works fine after fixing the column issue and inserting dummy items (number larger than the `height` of the listbox).

Comment: i run in a new py file and it works, but when come to my original main py it cant works.. here my codes for printing the result:

Comment: i found the issue, my result in list box is a string and cause my scroll bar cant works.. please help

Comment: The items in a listbox are strings, so I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: erm.. can you try to paste as edited above code and run in python3.8.. i tried but it could not work